# Typescript Enums in AngularJS HTML Attributes

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an Enum in typescript:

```
 enum EnumCountries{
     Canada=0,
     USA=1,
     Holland=2
}
```

In AngularJS I wish to use this in the HTML, but the following doesn't work:

```
 <div ng-show="model.country==EnumCountries.USA">
```

I'm trying to get away from magic numbers in the HTML

Comment: You need to assign your enum class to a `$scope` variable - `$scope.EnumCountries = EnumCountries`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use Enum in the HTML you need to specify an Enum as a variable.

You can do something like this in the component.ts:

```
enumCountries = EnumCountries;
```

And then in the component.html you can do:

```
<div ng-show="model.country == enumCountries.USA">
```